# How do I get Elixir Websockex to subscribe to a websocket?

Tags: elixir

I'm a newbie to Elixir/Erlang. By way of example, I'm trying to learn how to subscribe to a websocket feed.

I've copied the Websockex basic example:

```
defmodule WebSocketExample do
  use WebSockex

  def start_link(url, state) do
    WebSockex.start_link(url, __MODULE__, state)
  end

  def handle_frame({type, msg}, state) do
    IO.puts "Received Message - Type: #{inspect type} -- Message: #{inspect msg}"
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_cast({:send, {type, msg} = frame}, state) do
    IO.puts "Sending #{type} frame with payload: #{msg}"
    {:reply, frame, state}
  end
end
```

and am trying to instantiate it in iex with:

```
WebSocketExample.start_link "wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=instrument,quote:XBTUSD", state

(CompileError) iex:3: undefined function state/0
```

however I get the error that state is undefined.

I'm not sure what state should be (surely that's empty and gets passed around a loop?). Any tips that help me understand would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`state` here can be any value. You can use it to store information about the socket instance which can later be accessed in the handle functions. For example, you can pass a user id to `start_link` and access that from `handle_cast` and `handle_info`. If you don't want to keep any state, just pass any value, e.g. `:ok`:

```
WebSocketExample.start_link "wss://...", :ok
```